# Bootstrap 3.2 Feedback states not compiled

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Grunt with the latest NodeJS for windows to compile bootstrap 3.2.0 from getbootstrap.com. One thing I notice got no errors upon compiling but no Feedback states css classes are added/compiled to css file. Any help?

Comment: Please provide some working fiddle and explain your problem in brief

Comment: Ok. I downloaded a zip copy of bootstrap in http://getbootstrap.com  and had the latest NodeJS installed in my pc and installed GRUNT.  Followed all the instruction on the bootstrap page on how to compile only edited the variables.less and then compiled with 0 errors but upon testing the compiled bootstrap.css .has-warning/feedback states are missing it seems they aren't compiled into the css.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the answer to this. The provided form.less by http://getbootstrap.com has mistakes in the variable.

**Original Code:**

```
.has-success {
  @include form-control-validation($state-success-text, $state-success-text, $state-success-bg);
}
.has-warning {
  @include form-control-validation($state-warning-text, $state-warning-text, $state-warning-bg);
}
.has-error {
  @include form-control-validation($state-danger-text, $state-danger-text, $state-danger-bg);
}
```

**Fix**

```
.has-success {
  @include form-control-validation($state-success-text, $state-success-border, $state-success-bg);
}
.has-warning {
  @include form-control-validation($state-warning-text, $state-warning-border, $state-warning-bg);
}
.has-error {
  @include form-control-validation($state-danger-text, $state-danger-border, $state-danger-bg);
}
```

The var **$state-warning-text** was passed twice as parameter missing **$state-warning-border**.

Comment: It seems it was already reported by someone yet on their current release its still has that error.